# Easiest way to convert wikitext to plaintext

Tags: node.js, mediawiki, wikipedia

I am having a list of wikitext files (all .txt ), each file has wikitext markup , I want for each file , the corresponding plain text version , I tried using https://github.com/spencermountain/wtf_wikipedia , It does work individually for an article , but when iterating over all .txt file in a folder I am getting the following error , which I am having hard time debugging.

Error:

> /home/saurabh/node_modules/wtf_wikipedia/src/index.js:27   let arr =
>   Object.keys(data.sections).map(k => {
>                      ^
>
> TypeError: Cannot convert undefined or null to object
>       at Function.keys ()
>       at Object.plaintext (/home/saurabh/node_modules/wtf_wikipedia/src/index.js:27:20)
>       at /home/saurabh/Desktop/comprehension_burden/wikipedia_w2v/wiki_xml_to_jsonv4.js:71:32
>       at Array.forEach ()
>       at Object. (/home/saurabh/Desktop/comprehension_burden/wikipedia_w2v/wiki_xml_to_jsonv4.js:62:7)
>       at Module._compile (module.js:573:30)
>       at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:584:10)
>       at Module.load (module.js:507:32)
>       at tryModuleLoad (module.js:470:12)
>       at Function.Module._load (module.js:462:3)

Here is the code : https://gist.github.com/saurabhvyas/1b719f027984ea33864a15fd58bf1b9f

The number of files are huge , so I am looking for solution which has lowest time complexity

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would recommend [pandoc](http://pandoc.org/), it can convert from wikitext to plain text (and a whole lot of other formats too).

You'd do something like:

```
for F in *.wikitext; do
    pandoc -f mediawiki -o "$F.txt" "$F"
done
```

Comment: Thanks , I will definitely check pandoc !